# Sync Daedalus with a local testnet node

Tags: daedalus, testnet, node

I have set up a Cardano development environment and build a node which is fully synced to the testnet network.
How can I make my Daedalus wallet use/point to that local testnet node instead of synching again to the online/main testnet?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who may need a similar setup, I got this working after many trials. From my local cardano node, I copied the contents of the db directory into the `chain` directory of the Daedalus wallet.
I then updated the configuration file `topology.yaml` to use `localhost` in the addr parameter.

It works and I can receive tAda from the  testnet faucet.

Answer (score 0):

Daedalus is a full node itself, this mean that he doesn't connect to an external node to sync the blockchain.

As the [official website](https://daedaluswallet.io/) says:
*"Daedalus is a full node wallet. This means that unlike light wallets (e.g.Yoroi, Adalite etc.) Daedalus downloads a full copy of the Cardano blockchain and independently validates every transaction in its history."*

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/l1tcgx/how_daedalus_works_can_i_connect_it_to_my_running/) I found a Reddit Link where a similar question was made.

Comment: Well true, Daedalus is a full node, but on a fresh install ,it needs to connect to the Cardano network to sync to the latest blocks. What I was trying is to get it to use my local node which has already synced.